# What are the non-dev cases of SQL Server User Instances (vs CE and other embedded databases)?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, database-design

what are the cases of non-development practical (production use (design, development and deployment) of SQL Server (Express Edition) User Instances?
i.e. when you deploy them into production but not SQL Server CE (Compact Edition) or other embedded database?

Related question:
[What are in SQL Server User Instances that make them impossible in non-Express Editions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183485/what-are-in-sql-server-user-instances-that-make-them-impossible-in-non-express-ed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the same as Sql Server Ce, but where it's desirable that the data store be more robust. Also bear in mind that things like reporting services are available to Sql Server Express but not Ce, which can make a difference to the desirability of one over the other.